# SSO solutions for Django

Tags: django, openid, single-sign-on

I have several Django websites and I want to create a centralized auth provider. The auth provider site would contain the user accounts and be the only repository for user details and passwords. Users would log into the auth provider site and when they visit each satellite website for the first time, an account is created on that site. Subsequent visits to the satellite site would result in them being sent to the auth provider site to login first. On returning they are automatically logged in to the satellite site. My only difficulty is that the auth provider site would be on the internet and the satellite sites are in DMZs on private networks with access to the internet. So the satellite sites cannot establish any outgoing connections to the auth provider.

I still need the ability to log into the satellite sites using the locally configured admin user.

I looked at OAuth2 but I don't think that fits my needs. I'm currently reading about OpenID but I noticed a comment that the satellite server contacts the OpenID server, which cannot happen in my configuration. When I say OpenID I mean that I would have to run my own server as I need 100% control over the users. Are there any other solutions I've not mentioned yet that meet my requirements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is essentially SAML.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any good off-the-shelf open source solutions for this.

If you're looking for a service solution, the company I work at (Stormpath) provides a library that does this. It's free to use. https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-django